# How to handle large integers in IBM ILOG CPLEX CP Optimizer?

Tags: python, optimization, constraint-programming, ilog, cp-optimizer

This is a follow-up from [this post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=c63ec5e9-4ab8-42e2-b865-853f97174bb9&ps=25). In short, I am using [IBM ILOG CPLEX CP Optimizer](http://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/#constraint-programming-modeling-for-python-using-docplex-cp-docplex-cp) in Python to solve a constraint programming problem. One of the optimization objectives is to maximize the product of integers x_1 * x_2 * ... * x_n. As the problem scales up (e.g. *n* is around 300), the product will apparently get very large and CP Optimizer seemed to be unable to handle this large integer. For different values of *n*, the returned product was always 1.79769e+308.

Integers are unlimited in size and have no maximum value in native Python, so I guess CP Optimizer handles large integers differently. Is there any way to deal with large integers in CP Optimizer?

Some side notes:

- My program worked fine with smaller data sizes (small *n*).
- I tried maximizing log(x_1) + log(x_2) + ... + log(x_n) but the program was running non-stop. I reckon the *log* makes things complicated.
- For those who are interested, my source code and sample data is [here](https://github.com/PhuLai/sample-cp-optimizer/blob/master/bin-packing-variant.py).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That is the upper limit of float64 (so even this data-type fails for you; and is silently used in the core). As there is probably no support for arbitrary arithmetic, you might try to add upper bounds on that sum, coming from additional model-assumptions. Of course this somewhat assumes, that you are expecting a solution in this valid range.

Answer (score 1):

in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/refcppopl/html/variables/IlcIntMax.html

you may read

On 64-bit platforms, the largest positive integer which can be represented as a 64-bit floating point number according to IEEE 754, or the constant 2^53-1. On 32-bit platforms, the constant 2^31-1.

This upper limit should be respected when specifying domain values for the IlcIntVar class.